How to send the correct velocity percentage through ROS (fanuc_driver_exp)?
I am currently using the fanuc_driver_exp to command my CR-35ia through ROS, however I am unable to send the correct joint velocity percentages. After multiple attempts I have decided that I just don't understand what needs to be sent in order for ros_traj to read the correct value for vel_perc_, if anyone could provide me insight on this isue it would be great. 
